# Converting a wave equation from three to two dimensions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

[image]

I've recently been set the following problem in a takeaway paper and I have one small problem with my result.

Using the Leibniz integral rule I found:

$$u_t=v(x,t,t)+\int^t_0v_t(x,t;s)ds, u_x=\int^t_0v_x(x,t;s)ds$$
then following from that I got:
$$u_{tt}=2v_t(x,t,t)+\int^t_0v_{tt}(x,t;s)ds, u_{xx}=\int^t_0v_{xx}(x,t;s)ds$$
This is of course incorrect as this leaves the correct boundary conditions for u however u$_{tt}$-u$_{xx}$=2f(x,t) not f(x,t)? Where in my explanation is wrong? I feel like what I found was correct however I don't know how I could have got one of these v$_t$s out of my equation for u$_{tt}$.

Comment: Doing the step from $u_t$ to $u_{tt}$ I rather get
$$
u_{tt}=\partial_tv_t(x,t,t)+v_t(x,t,t)+\int_0^tv_{tt}(x,t;s)\,ds\,.
$$
Should we not require $\partial_tv_t(x,t,t)+v_t(x,t,t)=f(x,t)\,$? What has this to do with dimension reduction?

Comment: The v(x,t;t), as defined in the question is simply equal to zero, hence you can discard it in u$_t$ hence when u$_{tt}$ is finally computed you will have the correct result of u$_{tt}$-u$_{xx}$=v$_t$(x,t;t). Everything else you have done is correct.

Comment: Ok. $v(x,s;s)=0$ in your picture means $v(x,t;t)$ in $u_t\,.$ Then I get $$u_{tt}=\underbrace{v_t(x,t,t)}_{f(x,t)}+\int_0^tv_{tt}(x,t;s)\,ds\,.$$ This should answer your question. No?

Comment: @KurtG. Yes absolutely, I did eventually find that I don't know why I had a hard time getting the result. Thank you for your help.